# Pourquoi répond-on « de rien » à « merci » ?

Tags: expressions, sens, politesse

Il s'agit d'une question que je me suis toujours posée.

En effet *de rien* (littéralement *from nothing*) n'a, dans ce contexte, que très peu de sens.

D'ailleurs dans certaines régions de France, le retour d'un *merci* peut même être un beau « s'il vous plaît » (littéralement « *as it pleases you* ») qui semble beaucoup plus courtois et prend même tout son sens.

Plus poliment, on entendra parfois un « je vous en prie » ou « avec plaisir » qui ont également plus de sens que ce bien vide « de rien ».

Alors d'où vient-il ?

Comment: Le sens me paraît au contraire assez clair : par élégance et modestie, on minimise le service rendu au point de rendre inutile d'y faire mention. Un certain nombre d'expressions équivalentes sont bâties sur le même modèle : « il n'y a pas de quoi, » et les traductions *verbatim* de l'espagnol et de l'italien. Je pense d'ailleurs que « je vous en prie » est du même genre (n'en parlons plus, je vous en prie...)

Comment: effectivement, au vu des réponses le sens "de rien" semble en réalité plus puissant qu'il n'en ressort dans ces parfois très froids *"de rien"*. quoi qu'il en soit, **Merci** à vous ;)

Comment: Not "from nothing", but "for nothing", implying that "there is nothing I did to be thankful for."

Comment: Pour aller à contre courant de toutes les réponses jusqu'à présent, même si son usage est très répandu, certaines personnes estiment que _"De rien"_ n'est pas une réponse correcte à _"Merci"_, et ce pour plusieurs raisons. Tout d'abord la personne qui remercie le fait pour une raison, et répondre _"De rien"_ est brutal puisqu'il nie cette raison. Ensuite dire que ce n'était rien peut sous-entendre que l'on ne l'aurait pas fait sinon. Il est donc plus courtois de répondre _"Je vous en prie"_, _"Au plaisir"_ ou _"S'il vous plaît"_.

Comment: c'est justement cette impression négative qui se dégageait et que je trouvais étrange. mais au vu des réponses, l'abréviation fait perdre le contexte *ne me remerciez de rien* est en effet tellement plus riche que ce simple *de rien*

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Le [Littré](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise_%28Littr%C3%A9%29) classe [« de rien »](http://francois.gannaz.free.fr/Littre/xmlittre.php?rand=&requete=rien&submit=Rechercher#var4) (qu'il considère comme faisant partie de la langue populaire) au même sens que :

> **De rien (avec ne)**, nullement. *Elle ne peut de rien profiter ni aussi de rien nuire.* (Descartes) *Il ne sera pas dit que je ne serve de rien dans cette affaire-là*. (Molière) *Mon indulgence ne servirait de rien, il faut qu'elle [la demande en grâce] soit signée de trois autres de mes confrères.* (Voltaire)

C'est l'abbréviation d'une réponse plus longue qui serait « ne me remerciez de rien », « ne me remerciez nullement », ou aujourd'hui « ne me remerciez pas, ce n'était rien ».

Comment: *ne me remerciez de rien* l'expression prend en effet tout son sens dans ce contexte. Dommage alors que ce *de rien* sonne si froid tout seul.

Comment: @apouche Le ton peut aider *de rien* à sonner de façon plus chaleureuse. Ne serait-ce que sous la forme d'une exclamation : *de rien !*

Comment: Et pour les curieux, on trouvera dans les commentaires de la [réponse de Shlublu](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/944/1514) diverses autres options. Je pense que ça gagnerait à être inclus dans la réponse acceptée, ou la question @apouche

Answer (score 10):

Normalement, il faudrait utiliser « de rien » dans des contextes où l'on veut dire que le « merci » ne s'impose pas, qu'il est de trop, superflu. Cela veut dire que l'on considère ce que l'on vient de faire comme « naturel », « normal », que ce n'est pas grand chose.

> — Merci de m'avoir raccompagné.
>   — Mais ce n'est rien, c'était sur mon chemin.

Donc « de rien » se traduirait mieux par : « *That's nothing* ». C'est maintenant devenu plus un stéréotype qu'autre chose et on répond machinalement « de rien » à tous les « merci ».

Answer (score 9):

*De rien* a beaucoup de sens, au contraire : il signifie *il n'y a aucune raison de me remercier, je n'ai rien fait de particulier*. Ce qui est une façon de dire :

- soit que l'on estime sincèrement ne pas mériter de remerciement car l'acte est naturel, ou encore obligatoire :

> — Merci de m'avoir emmené à l'hôpital lorsque tu m'as trouvé grièvement blessé.
>   — Bah… de rien voyons !

- soit que l'on souhaite répondre poliment, bien que méritant le remerciement :

> — Tu pourras venir me chercher à 50km d'ici, cette nuit à deux heures du matin ?
>   — A deux heures ? Bon d'accord.
>   — Merci !
>   — De rien…

Pour répondre à *merci*, on utilise aussi *je vous en prie*, ou encore *il n'y a pas de quoi*. Le sens de ce dernier est en tous points similaire à *de rien*.

Comment: +1 mais pas tout à fait d'accord, suite a une excursion dans la Lorraine, 2 personnes différentes (mais liées par la même profession de service) m'ont répondu *s'il vous plaît* quand il recevait un *merci*. J'en ai conclu, peut être hâtivement, que les Lorrains répondaient différemment.

Comment: S'agissait-il de deux personnes natives ? Car je n'ai entendu *s'il vous plaît* en réponse à un merci en France que deux ou trois fois dans toute ma vie. Il s'agissait toujours de personnes non francophones et qui avaient la gentillesse de s'exprimer en français. J'ai pu passer à côté d'un régionalisme, bien sûr, mais tout de même cela m'étonne. Y a-t-il un Lorrain dans la salle ? ;)

Comment: @Shlublu SVP en réponse à merci, c'est standard au Luxembourg, et je crois aussi en France près de la frontière.

Comment: Ok, j'ai édité ma réponse pour en tenir compte. Merci!

Comment: « S'il vous plaît » semble commun en Belgique, tout au moins d'après mes fréquentations, soit Wallons soit Flamands parlant wallon. Dans le sud de la France j'entends--et je dis-- « avec plaisir », à quoi on peut enchérir avec « le plaisir est pour moi » ou « le plaisir est partagé ».

Comment: @Shlubu les lorrains à la rescousse ! ;-) Mieux vaut tard que jamais... pour dire que je n'ai jamais entendu cette réponse ici, ayant vécu à peu près autant en Moselle qu'en Meurthe-et-Moselle... il reste l'éventualité d'un usage en patois vosgien ou meusien que je n'aurais encore pas rencontré, mais j'en doute. Ici, les anciens répondent « Service ! ».

Comment: "Service" ? J'aime beaucoup !

Comment: Continuons… Au Québec, on dit *Bienvenue*. D'après le [wiktionary](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/bienvenue), c'est en calque de l'anglais *welcome*, mais je suis sûr que ça a plein de plus jolies façons de s'interpréter, à base de "vous êtes bienvenu à me demander de l'aide", etc.

Comment: @mouviciel rem: le wallon est une langue endogène (de moins en moins parlée). En wallon "de rien/pas de quoi" donnent "gn a ren avou ça". Ceci étant dit, "s'il vous plaît" n'est pas tellement commun en Wallonie.

Answer (score 0):

« De rien », lorsqu'utilisé avec sincérité et à partir du cœur, signifie pour moi :

> Tu n'es pas en dette vis-à-vis de moi, j'affirme que tu restes libre, même si tu reçois le service que je te rends.