# Ways of saying “you're welcome” in French

Tags: politesse

After someone says “*merci beaucoup*”, I would like to respond by saying something equivalent to the English phrase “*no problem*”.  I tried google translate, and it gave me “*Pas de problème*”, but I'm not so sure this is correct.  Is it correct?  Are there other informal ways of expressing “you're welcome”?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

There are a few main ways to say "you're welcome" in French:

- *Je vous en prie / Je t'en prie*

I feel this is a little more formal than the others, but is the canonical French response to "thank you". In some sense, it can be equivalent to "don't worry about it".

- *Pas de problème*

Google translate was right. It is widely used, it's informal and it likely comes from English in the first place.

- *De rien*

This phrase likely comes from the Spanish *de nada*. *Rien* means "nothing", so it could be somewhat analogous to "don't give it a second thought". But shorter and more informal.

- *Bienvenue*

Used in Canada, this is the literal translation of "welcome". In other French-speaking countries, it would likely not be understood. This use of *bienvenue* is an anglicism; its correct use is mostly one of greeting or of appreciation, like when you say, for example, that relief is welcomed.

Comment: If we come to regional languages, let's add one we hear in Lorraine, mainly from older people : *Service !*

Comment: My native language is French and I wouldn't have understood that Romain Valeri.

Comment: *Bienvenue* would definitely not be understood in that context in France.

Comment: _Pas de problème_ est, je pense, un anglicisme.

Comment: _Service !_ is very common in the french part of Switzerland also, and not only from older people...

Comment: @rds 'Pas de problème' n'est pas un anglicisme. 'Bienvenue' par contre en est clairement un.

Comment: @RomainVALERI: Service means at your service, it means that people that said that has to be at service; for instance a barman to a customer, isn't it?

Comment: @clement No, in this case, it can be used regardless of any relationship between the locutors (if informal speech is admitted, I mean). It's a real substitute for *de rien* even if its apparent etymology would make you think otherwise.

Comment: *Il n'y a pas de quoi* is also verry used.

Answer (score 24):

Other ways to answer a "*Merci*" are:

- "*Il n'y a pas de quoi*", sometimes abbreviated in "*Pas de quoi*"
- around Toulouse: "*Avec plaisir*"
- in Belgium: "*S'il vous plaît*"

Comment: +1 for *Pas de quoi*

Comment: _Avec plaisir_ is more formal. I went to a high-end restaurant and the waiter was answering _Avec beaucoup de plaisir_ after my thanks.

Comment: @rds - I live in Toulouse and *Avec plaisir* is very common and not formal at all.

Comment: Why only around Toulouse? I think "*Avec plaisir*" is commonly used everywhere in France.

Comment: @Otiel - Because friends from other regions find it strange.

Comment: @Otiel I never heard this one. So I wouldn't agree with 'used everywhere in France'.

Comment: @Otiel : Born and bred in Toulouse and now living north of the Loire I can assure that « avec plaisir » (to be quite accurate */a.ve/ plaisir*) is commonly used in Toulouse and sounds strange to northerners  even when « avec » is pronouced /a.vɛk/.

Comment: In Belgium, we say “S’il vous plaît” when we hand something to someone, so *before* “merci”, but I’ve never heard “s’il vous plaît” as an *answer* to merci.

Comment: @Édouard - I'm sure having heard it in Bruges after saying _merci_ to waiters in restaurants (they all speak french to french tourists)

Comment: But, despite their (usually great) french, most of them are not native speakers. I would still avoid it.

Comment: There's also *De rien* in Quebec, but informal

Comment: @edouard: you can sometimes hear "s'il vous plait" as reply to "merci" in Brussels, under the influence of Dutch. I would tentatively say however that the usage is on the decrease, I rather associate it with older speakers and would not imagine someone younger than 40 still using it nowadays.

Comment: @Greg: Interesting to learn that it's from Dutch. While staying in Brussels in 2001, I've been told "s'il vous plait" by waiters many times. At first, I was misunderstanding it and I thought they were asking me to repeat what I said, as if "S'il vous plait, pouvez-vous répéter?" so I would just say "Merci" again, a little louder. However it happened too often, so I asked someone who clarified it was an equivalent to "Je vous en prie".

Comment: @Max:true story: last year, I was on holiday in Portugal. In a small snack-bar in Sintra, one of the waiters heard we were speaking French, so when he brought the dishes, he answered my "obrigado" with a big smile, a wink and a loud "s'il-vous-plait", which surprised me to hear used in the Belgian fashion. We chatted a bit: he had never studied French in school, but had learned it the hard way by working in a restaurant in... Brussels...

Answer (score 13):

The usual answer to “*merci*” in French is “*de rien*” which has about the same meaning as “no problem” and translates to “it's nothing”.

Comment: Littré says "_de rien_" is familair language for a depricated _ne me remerciez de rien_ http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/940/pourquoi-repond-on-de-rien-a-un-merci

Answer (score 10):

The most commonly used is probably **"De rien"**.

Slightly more formal is this one : **"Je t'en prie / Je vous en prie"**

Your **"Pas de problème"** is used also, and is more casual.

Comment: I don't think "_pas de souci(s?)_" nor "_pas de problème_" are good answers after "_merci_". I think, they fit better after "_excuse-moi_".

Comment: @rds I guess that as for many casual idioms, it varies quite a lot between regions. Your logic is right, but following it, this it would also invalidate half of the expressions commonly used to communicate any meaning ;-) Am I really *at the mercy* (*Merci*) of anyone who's kind enough to hold the door more than one second ?

Answer (score 7):

À l'oral, après **merci**, en France (St Etienne)  j'entends souvent répondre *Y'a pas d'soucis*.

Comment: I don't think "_pas de souci(s?)_" nor "_pas de problème_" are good answers after "merci". I think, they fit better after "excuse-moi".

Comment: @rds Yse and no, in my opinion. _Merci_ means _Vous vous êtes géné pour me rendre service_, it's sort of _excuse-moi_, you right. So the response _Y'a pas d'soucis_ is understandable. It's common conversation : _Merci / Y'a pas d'soucis / Mais merci quand même / y'a pas d'soucis y'a pas d'soucis je t'assure_ and so on. Sorry for my english (Y'a pas d'soucis).

Answer (score 5):

I do use "avec plaisir". I find those one (below) strange even if they are more common. 
(What follows is just my very personal interpretation).

1. "Je t'en prie / Je vous en prie" sound a bit arrogant/posh,
   like: nooo please, it's ok, don't thank me dear, really, no I insist don't, oh dear...
2. "Il n'y a pas de quoi" looks absurd, as if we needed a scale to
   thanks somebody. "No it's not enough, you can't thank me. (It sounds
   also like #1)
3. "Pas de problème" or "y'a pas de soucis"  is the most common, it
       sounds like: you did not bother me too much, just a little, but it's
       ok (but you did...)
4. "De rien": do fit for guys who aren't able to accept things (good or bad)
   from the others. "You don't own me anything and I don't own you
   anything, let's stop talking". (It sounds also like #3)
5. "Bienvenue" sound from quebec (so, funny), but it provides a warm answer, I like it.

Note that french are still very attach to their old formal way of talking: sometime  spontaneity and warmth do make the french uncomfortable. But "avec plaisir" works with anybody, even if it sounds spontaneous and shows warmth it also somehow shows some formal "politeness".

Comment: You seem quite a lot more generous with your last interpretation (to justify *avec plaisir*) than with any other. If we apply the same (a bit cynical) views on *avec plaisir*, I can guarantee you that some people will think it sounds hypocritical or some even out-of-place sensual reference... Once again it varies a lot with place and time, so maybe it's sometimes better not to infer too much.

Comment: @RomainVALERI interesting, I did not think about that! But what you said, the intonation, is working with any word, you could change the meaning of "merci" or even "salut". But those words, even if we forget about it "de rien" have a clear meaning and (in my view) correspond to different psychological profile.

Answer (score 3):

In Northern France, I most frequently hear "Il n'y a pas de quoi", or just "pas de quoi" (more casual).

Answer (score 1):

From simple : "De rien", to more formal: "Pas de quoi" ou "il n'y a pas de quoi", and more polite: "Je vous en prie", "je t'en prie". "Pas de problème" est plus récent et semble importé du sabir globish...