# Que répondre à un merci mérité ? — Which answer to a much deserved “merci”?

Tags: usage, vocabulaire, politesse

Il existe bien des manières de répondre à ***merci***. Chacune a sa signification.

- [Ne me remercie] *De rien*.
- [À ton] *Service*.
- *Il n'y a pas de quoi* [me remercier].
- *C'est tout naturel* [ce que je fais pour toi].
- *C'est un plaisir* [de te rendre service].
- etc.

Y a-t-il une manière de répondre « *tes remerciements sont bien mérités, car ce que j'ai fait n'est ni naturel, ni un plaisir et sache que je ne suis pas à ton service* » ? Si possible d'une façon moins pompeuse et plus polie que celle-ci.

---

Each of the many ways to answer ***merci*** has a specific meaning in French:

- *De rien* (it was nothing)
- *Service* (at your service)
- *Il n'y a pas de quoi* (nothing to worry about)
- *C'est tout naturel* (of course)
- *C'est un plaisir* (my pleasure)

How to formulate an answer along the lines “*your thanks are well deserved, because what I did was neither natural nor a pleasure and please notice that I'm not your servant*” in a less clumsy and more polite way?

Comment: Ne rien dire, juste sourire?

Comment: Oui, bien sûr, c'est ce qui m'est venu à l'esprit. Je voulais savoir s'il y avait une version orale de ce geste.

Comment: À mon sens à part *service*, aucun n'implique ni naturel ni plaisir ni service, ce sont simplement des formules de politesse (fonction phatique, préservation de face, Jakobson, Goffman, tout ça). Si l'objectif est d'insister sur le fait que c'est mérité, je ne voit pas vraiment comment faire sans que ça puisse être considéré comme insultant.

Comment: J'adore cette question. Il faudrait pouvoir voter 2 fois :) Mais actuellement, je trouve qu'il n'y a pas encore de réponse satisfaisante...

Comment: Qu'est-ce qu'un *merci mérité* ? C'est quand l'interlocuteur a effectivement raison de dire qu'il est **à ma merci** ? Jamais je n'ai eu le sentiment qu'un merci qu'on m'adressait était (au sens littéral) mérité... Même quand on a rendu un réel service à quelqu'un, on peut rester poli et répondre "normalement" à  son *merci*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Informal ways of saying "you're welcome" in French](http://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/informal-ways-of-saying-youre-welcome-in-french)

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu *service* seul.

Comment: C'est sans doute la réponse à *merci* la plus courante en Suisse, tu devrais venir y faire un tour, l'air est frais et les gens chaleureux.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Plus court :

> Je vous en prie.

Brève politesse formelle totalement neutre, où seule la façon et le ton de la formulation donne le sens que l'on veut lui attribuer.

Comment: Surtout que *je vous en prie* ne précise pas de quoi je vous prie. C'est vraiment la réponse la plus neutre ! elle peut être autant comprise comme *je vous en prie, inutile de vous remercier* que comme *je vous en prie, ne me demandez plus jamais de faire ça*.

Comment: Je suis pas entièrement d'accord. L'usage très commun de cette pharse dans le sens "Ca ne m'a pas ennuyé du tout" ou surtout dans le domaine du commerce de détail,s où la personne est carrément payée pour rendre ce service, sous-entend que dire merci n'est "pas nécessaire".

Comment: Il me semble qu'il y a encore plus de déférence dans *je vous en prie* que dans *de rien* ou *à votre service*. Cette réponse est effectivement très courante après un *merci* mais il me semble que c'est totalement hors-sujet étant donné la formulation de la question (vouloir signifier *...ce que j'ai fait n'est ni naturel, ni un plaisir et sache que je ne suis pas à ton service...*)

Comment: @RomainVALERI Si quelqu'un que je remercie me dit *de rien* ou *à votre service*, je prends cela comme une invitation à recommencer. Un *je vous en prie* glacial, sans aucun autre commentaire, me douche immédiatement et rompt toute conversation sur le sujet en question, et donc empêche toute future demande. En plus il y a une forme d'élégance à ne pas se plaindre de l'effort effectué pour rendre service, et de laisser autres sujets d'échanges possibles. "L'accusé de réception" du merci se fait dans l'intonation, pas dans le commentaire, et dépend entièrement du contexe.

Comment: Tu compares un *de rien* (supposé neutre voire positif) avec un *je vous en prie* **glacial**, ce qui biaise la comparaison. Compare également un *de rien* **glacial** avec un aimable *je vous en prie*... qu'en penses-tu ?

Comment: @RomainVALERI Le *de rien* est plutôt une tournure familière que je ne saurais employer en toute circonstance, et il me semble difficile de répondre *de rien* s'il m'en a réellement couté, sauf sous une forme ironique, ou une litote qui pourrait m'obliger à détailler les difficultés rencontrées. Mais il est tout à fait possible de les échanger selon les situations

Answer (score 19):

Une expression comme :

> à charge de revanche

me semble convenir, on y retrouve, en effet, cette notion de  « je l'ai fait volontiers, mais ce n'est pas gratuit! »

Comment: (+1) C'est la seule réponse qui me semble pertinente quant à l'énoncé. On exprime ici clairement que *ce n'était pas gratuit* et qu'on accepte volontiers (et même qu'on attend) plus que de la gratitude mais un réel « retour d'ascenseur ».

Comment: +1 Avec un sourire ou un clin d'oeil, pour faire comprendre que le service n'est pas entièrement gratuit !

Comment: Il y a un équivalent dans certaines situations : « Vous en auriez fait tout autant pour moi/si vous aviez été à ma place », qui implique là encore qu'il serait bon que l'interlocuteur nous rende la pareille dans un cas semblable.

Answer (score 7):

Je pense que personnellement, je ne réponds rien. Mais il y a le langage non verbal qui intervient qui consiste généralement en un large sourire.

Si la situation se passe au téléphone, par exemple, ne pas répondre est probablement impossible ou bizarre. Donc, dans ce cas, je transmettrais ce que mon sourire signifie, c-à-d : « Écoute, ça me fait plaisir que tu me remercies. »

Comment: Ça me fait plaisir que tu me répondes :-P

Comment: Mouarf! Belle répartie :-)

Answer (score 5):

> Il fallait bien que quelqu'un le fasse / se donne la peine de le faire

Cela traduit le côté non naturel, et l'effort qui a été nécessaire pour accomplir le service. De plus, ceci n'implique pas que le service sera obligatoirement rendu de nouveau dans le futur.

On pourra aussi utiliser une des expressions indiquées dans la question, tout dépendra alors du ton employé. Dit sur un ton paternaliste, limite condescendant,

> Mais ce n'est rien, voyons!

fera très bien l'affaire.

Answer (score 4):

Pour compléter la liste initiale, j'utilise généralement :

> avec plaisir

Et je me demande si cette expression est bien diffusée partout ou si c'est une expression plus commune dans la région Toulousaine.

Et je rajouterais :

> Mais c'est tout à fait normal (voyons) !

Pour répondre à la question, je propose :

> Bien sûr.

Answer (score 3):

Dans ce cas, je réponds généralement :

> Content que tu apprécies.

...à supposer bien sûr d'être effectivement content que l'autre ait apprécié (par son remerciement) le service rendu. C'est une façon de dire « merci pour ton merci ».

Si le but est plutôt d'insister sur l'effort fourni ou inviter à ne plus redemander ce genre de chose, je ne vois pas trop de formule générale, dans ce cas je répondrais quelque chose comme :

> Content que ce soit terminé !

ou

> Ce n'était pas une mince affaire !

Answer (score 1):

Tout simplement, je pense à :

> Vous le méritez (Tu le mérites)

Cette formule est polie, ne signifie pas que ce j'ai fais est naturel ou forcément un plaisir. De plus, cela signifie que je t'ai aidé sur ce coup là mais ce ne sera peut être pas le cas la prochaine fois. J'ai juste estimé que tu méritais de l'aide cette fois-ci.

Answer (score 0):

When I lived in Geneva, the standard response by shopkeepers to my "merci" was "c'est moi" (= "c'est moi qui dois vous remercier").

Comment: OK, mais ça ne répond pas à la question. Si un ami débouche mes toilettes durant 1h et que je lui dis "merci", il ne va pas me répondre "c'est moi". Dans ma question, le remerciement est mérité, dire "c'est moi" fait justement l'inverse et retourne la situation.