# Origine de l'expression « s'il vous plaît » en donnant/tendant quelque chose à quelqu'un

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Quelle est l'origine de l'utilisation de « s'il vous plaît » lorsque l'on tend ou donne un objet à quelqu'un ?

L'utilisation me semble fortement régionale (Nord de la France et Belgique *a minima*) et on trouve des équivalents dans plusieurs langues germaniques (*bitte shön* en allemand, *alstublieft* en flamand, mais pas uniquement : on trouve l'usage d'*ορίστε* en grec par exemple) qui pourraient peut-être expliquer l'origine de l'usage (par proximité régionale), mais ce n'est qu'une supposition de ma part.

Comment: Il me semble que *ορίστε* est un impératif. Cela fait, à mes yeux une nuance importante par rapport aux autres formules citées.

Comment: Une autre question sur un thème similaire: [Ways of saying “you're welcome” in French](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2933/364)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toutes les sources indiquent que ce *s'il vous plait* est un [flandricisme](http://belgicisme.blogg.org/s-il-vous-plait-a116055832).

Quant à son utilisation en Belgique ou ailleurs, elle n'a rien d'illogique que ce soit quand elle est utilisée en tendant quelque chose à quelqu'un (***Voici/tenez, s'il vous plait***<sup>1</sup>) ou quand on demande à quelqu'un de répéter quelque chose (***Pardon ? / Plait-il ?***).

<sup>1</sup><sub>S'il vous plait permet de neutraliser l'impératif *tenez* sous entendu. On aurait pu dire en français littéraire: ***Libre à vous s'il vous plait de le prendre***.</sub>

Comment: Pour la compréhension de la logique, à, *s'il vous plait* j'ajouterais l'implicite *de le prendre*. Une sorte de conditionnel par opposition à un *Tenez*! qui est de fait plus impératif.

Comment: @aCOSwt Ajouté, merci !