# Quel est le sens (à l'origine) de l'expression «Je vous en prie», après un «Merci»?

Tags: sens, expressions, expressions-idiomatiques, politesse, étymologie

En réponse à un «Merci», il existe [plusieurs formules](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/2933/informal-ways-of-saying-youre-welcome-in-french) de politesse dont «Je vous en prie» ou «Je t'en prie».

Au-delà de la simple formule de politesse, qu'est-ce que cette expression signifie à l'origine ?

Il y a une réponse intéressante [ici](https://fr.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080314030709AAn3pkc), mais elle ne me satisfait pas complètement.

Comment: Intuitivement, j'aurais tendance à dire que c'est une ellipse : "Je vous en prie [, n'en parlons plus]" ou "Je vous prie [de ne plus en faire mention]"

Comment: @guillaume31, hmmm, donc c'est pareil à l'expression "don't mention it" en anglais non?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Beaucoup de langues connaissent une interaction semblable de la paire *merci* – *prie*.
En allemand *Danke* est suivi par *Bitte* par exemple, mais [on le trouve dans d'autres langues aussi](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2572624).

Pour comprendre cette convention là, il faut avoir conscience de l'interaction entière.

Une demande et sa satisfaction se déroulent comme cela :

1. prier
2. accepter
3. remercier
4. prier (← la phrase en question)

On peut voir que la phrase en question est la conclusion symétrique de l'interaction entière, faisant écho à la demande initiale.

Je traduirais donc la phrase « je vous en prie » par :

> Je souhaitais, que vous me demandiez ça en premier lieu.

Aucune dette ne reste, l'interaction est conclue.

Comment: +1 pour le lien exceptionnel. Pour la réponse, j'aimerais bien un peu plus de détails : que veut dire *Bitte*, exactement ? qu'est-ce que vous entendez par "prier" en 4. ? on observe effectivement une certaine forme de symétrie, mais en quoi le donneur peut-il se faire le symétrique du receveur, exactement ? De quoi le donneur prie-t-il le receveur, et pourquoi ne le fait-il pas au passé, par exemple ?

Comment: Concernant la forme: conventions ont une vie autonome parfois et la brièveté peut avoir la priorité ||  "Bitte", si pas utilisé comme un substantif(la demande), est une contraction(brièveté voila) de la phrase "Ich bitte Sie" ("Je vous en prie”). || "Prier" en 4. est une generalisation de l'acte de demander.

Comment: Tous les deux(donneur et receveur) font la symétrie pour CONCLURE l'interaction, comme on FERME un livre par mettre ensemble les deux paquet de feuilles en face. C’est une geste sans contenu, mais partie de la interaction meme. L'interaction ne dois pas laisser des traces pour etre fini.||  On se débarrase de la interaction || Une autre convention illustre ça plus bien est peut etre: "Merci beaucoup!" "De rien"

Answer (score 6):

Pour moi la réponse « je vous en prie » a toujours eu le sens initial de **« je vous en prie, ne me remerciez pas »** (autrement dit « ne me remerciez pas s'il vous plaît »), ce qui exprime qu'on considère le service rendu comme insignifiant ou allant de soi. On répond cela, soit au premier degré parce qu'on le pense vraiment, soit en formule de politesse qui revient à le prétendre par modestie.

On retrouve la même idée dans « ce n'est rien » / [« de rien »](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/940/pourquoi-repond-on-de-rien-a-merci), « [il n'y a] pas de quoi » ou « c'est tout naturel », d'autres possibilités équivalentes de réponse à un remerciement. Chacune de ces formulations peut être employée au premier degré ou comme formule de politesse.

De la même façon, on peut aussi répondre « je vous en prie » à :

- « pardon » / « excusez-moi », le sens initial étant alors « je vous en prie, ne vous sentez pas fautif »
- une demande de permission (par exemple « je peux utiliser votre téléphone ? »), le sens initial étant alors « je vous en prie, ne demandez pas et faites directement »
- « après vous » (où quelqu'un propose à un autre de passer devant), le sens initial étant alors « je vous en prie, ne me proposez pas »

On peut même dire « je vous en prie » pour dire à quelqu'un d'arrêter un certain comportement (« je vous en prie, ça devient gênant/pénible », ou par exemple [« je vous en prie, vous parlez au premier ministre »](http://savoir.fr/vous-parlez-au-premier-ministre-de-la-france)). Dans tous les cas j'y vois à l'origine un sens commun de « je vous en prie, ne remerciez/demandez/proposez/faites pas ceci ».

Comment: Je ne suis pas d'accord. Ma mère m'a toujours appris à dire "Je vous en prie" (ou "A votre service") plutôt que "De rien", car elle trouvait que répondre "de rien", c'était malpoli. Il n'y a pas de modestie dans "de rien". J'ai fait cette action parce qu'elle était insignifiante ; autrement dit, aurais-je rendu service si celui-ci était contraignant pour ma personne ? Lorsque je dis "je vous en prie", je ne me réfère pas à au service rendu lui-même : je rends ce service avec plaisir, quel qu'il soit.

Comment: @MonsieurTruite Soit. _« elle trouvait que répondre "de rien", c'était malpoli »_ : c'est son avis, et pas le mien, libre à vous de vous faire le vôtre. :) Merci de souligner qu'on peut effectivement dire « de rien » sans modestie, parce qu'on considère simplement que l'action était insignifiante : j'ai ajouté cela dans ma réponse. Mais je trouve que c'est tout aussi valable pour « je vous en prie » et les autres, et je ne vois rien de malpoli là-dedans, qu'on utilise ces formulations au premier degré ou par modestie.

Comment: Malpoli, c'est bien sûr exagéré. Mais factuellement, répondre à quelqu'un que le service que l'on vient de lui rendre "n'est rien" est sans doute beaucoup moins courtois que l'idée que l'on se fait de "de rien" ! Cette dernière et "je vous en prie" sont deux expressions à des niveaux bien différents !

Answer (score 3):

Il me semble que l'expression peut aussi vouloir dire : « Il n'y a pas de quoi », dans le sens « ne vous en faite pas, cela ne me pose pas de problème. »

> - Je suis désolé de cette attente.
> - Je vous en prie.

Me confirmez-vous ?